# How to put a MySQL table column as a variable in <script>?

Tags: java, php, html, mysql, chat

I recently made a PHP, HTML, jQuery chat system and I want the users to have the same name in chat, as their login. The whole webpage is already connected to the MySQL database. I want to focus on how to put a `$_SESSION(login_user)`; as a variable in the jQuery script. Can somebody help me out?

```
    var name = [display username];
```

Comment: Do not confuse Java and Javascript in your tags. The two languages are about as related as Austria and Australia.

Comment: I am sorry I'm not usually using <script> in my coding I just use PHP and HTML most of the time.

Comment: When a user login your system you easily get the all information about the user and pass this value in your javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript itself can't access the session data. Hence you don't have access to the username directly.

There's a few ways you can get the username. One is like **Way to Developer** described and just shove php code inside a script tag.

However since this is not really sensible data I would add that info to your body as a data attribute and then access it with javascript directly.

```
<body data-username="<?php echo (isset($_SESSION['username'])) ? $_SESSION['username'] : null; ?> "
```

Then in your javascript you can just do (since you tagged jquery I assume you're using it):

```
var username = $('body).data('username');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get like below

```
var name = "<?php echo $_SESSION(login_user); ?>";
```

Comment: replace with this echo  isset($_SESSION[login_user]) ? $_SESSION[login_user] : ""; instead